# Trouble with Multi-Column (CSS3)

Tags: list, css, menu, media-queries, multiple-columns

I've troubles with the implementation of the multi-column in CSS3 for a menu list of items with description.

See the [Demo](http://www.brusinoarsizio.ch/indice/) for live view.

Practically, I use media-queries for change the number of columns when resizing the browser window, but in the case I have 3 column, I get an error at the top of the second column.

In fact, the description has to be at the bottom the last item of the first column, as obvious.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
column-break-inside: avoid;
```

To your:

```
#indice ul li
```

Selector.